# Creating Child Theme. "Warning: file_get_contents9():failed to open stream: No such file or directory" Error

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to create a child theme from my current theme (Tesseract 2). I've followed the instruction as specified [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) however I am continually receiving the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/home/fletcher/public_html/wp-content/themes/tesseract-child/css/typicons.css): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/fletcher/public_html/wp-content/themes/TESSERACT/inc/beaver-builder-modules/link-button/link-button-module.php on line 44.
```

I can remove this error by disabling the plugin (Beaver Builder Plugin (Lite Version)) however as I use this plugin on my site, this isn't really a viable option.

The childs `style.css` file:

```
/*
  Theme Name:     Tesseract-child
  Description:    Tesseract Child Theme
  Author:         
  Template:       TESSERACT
*/
```

The childs `functions.php` file:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the child CSS file actually named 'style.css'? The error is for a missing 'typicons.css' file.

Comment: Yes, the child CSS file is named 'style.css'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was causing this bug and it is now fixed.

The issue was with the PHP version that my host was using (5.3). Switching the PHP version to 5.6 fixed the issue.